# < Form > Code error. Unable to get email sent

Tags: html, css, forms

Here's the code:

http://shrib.com/9ZMmFhrY

not receiving emails when the is submitted. I want an email to be sent to my email when clicked on "submit"

Comment: There's not enough information to go on. What kind of server-side scripting are you using? Usually you need to POST submissions to a server.

Comment: _'Here's the code'_ - where? The relevant code should be posted in the question and the relevant language tagged as well.

Answer (score -1):

No matter what the code won't work. You need to have a form action. your form looks like this

```
<form action=>
```

you should at least leave it blank for self

```
<form action="form.php">
```

or

```
<form action="">
```

you also have no method such as post or get, so we don't know what the form is intending to do. What issues are you having when submitting with this?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I'd say the reason is more to do with the question than your answer. This is an awful question and should be closed forthwith. We can't actually judge the quality of your answer because the question is so bad. Answering a question like this only encourages others to post equally bad questions. Some folks here consider that such answers should be downvoted to discourage them.

Comment: There was an attached code file, I gave the OP an attempt at pointing them in the right direction. I agree some questions are horrible but sometimes people really don't know how to ask, I was merely trying to point in the right direction. There was definitely primary issues with the OPs code that would block it from working, period. That being, I agree this should just get closed, no activity and didn't search prior to posting.